# Handle Null XML Element

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

I am running this line of code, which executes perfect for roughly 800 of my records.  It hits record 801, and I am thrown

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in XMLPost.exe
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is the troublesome line of code, which I thought adding in the `?.Value` would account for null elements.

```
string sr12 = xml.Element("Parent").Element("Child1").Element("Child2").Element("Child3").Element("Child4").Element("Child5").Element("sr12")?.Value;
Console.WriteLine(sr12);
```

What should I alter for my variable `sr12` so that it does not break and my code can continue to execute as expected?

**EDIT**
XML Structure

```
<parent>
<one>
    <two>
        <three>
            <sr12></sr12>
        </three>
    </two>
</one>
  <ten>
    <eleven>
        <twelve>
            <thirteen>
                <sr12></sr12>
            </thirteen>
        </twelve>
    </eleven>
  </ten>
</parent>
```

I have also tried this syntax

```
var result = (string) xml.Elements("Parent")
.Elements("ten")
.Elements("eleven")   
.Elements("twelve")
.Elements("thirteen")
.Elements("homeaddress")
.SingleOrDefault();
```

Which produces an error of

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll
>  Additional information: Sequence contains more than one element

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186796/how-to-check-particular-attributes-exist-or-not-in-xml

Comment: What if any of the other Element("xx") elements is null? You just check if Element("sr12") is null.

Comment: Don't use value : string sr12 = (string)xml.Element("Parent").Element("Child1").Element("Child2").Element("Child3").Element("Child4").Element("Child5").Element("sr12");

Comment: @Nebr - I use the ?.Value; for all elements I am attempting to return with my XML - this is the only one that throws an error

Comment: @jdweng - same error if I use your syntax.

Comment: The "?."-syntax does not automatically check if all child nodes are present. If, for example, node "Child3" does not exist, a NullReferenceException will still be thrown.

Comment: @Nebr - all child nodes do exist.  I know that for a fact.

Comment: Then maybe for some reason "xml" itself is null? What does your debugger say when you hover over the expression?

Comment: The error indicates you are missing one of the intermediate elements.  I would use Descendants("sr12").FirstOrDefault() instead.

Comment: @jdweng - that gives me an error of The name 'Descendants' does not exist in the current context

Comment: The answer by @Charles Mager will solve your issue.  Are you sure that it is the same field throwing the error each time or is it a different field?  Again, the code provided will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If *any* of the elements in your query is missing, you will get this exception. The `Element` query either returns an `XElement` or it returns `null`.

You should use the `Elements` query. This returns *all* elements that match the name, and can be chained in the same way. The result of using this method would be that if any of the elements are missing, you simply get an empty sequence.

If you then call `SingleOrDefault` at the end, it will return either the single element returned by your query or null. You can then make use of the built in explicit conversion to string.

```
var result = (string) xml.Elements("Parent")
    .Elements("Child1")
    .Elements("Child2")   
    .Elements("Child3")
    .Elements("Child4")
    .Elements("Child5")
    .Elements("sr12")
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Alternatively, if the absolute path is not that important (it may be that `sr12` only appears at one point in the hierarchy), then you could use `Descendants`:

```
var result = (string) xml.Descendants("sr12").SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I get this error - 'XElement' does not contain a definition for 'SingleOrDefault' and no extension method 'SingleOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'XElement' could be found

Comment: @ToastedBreadLeavesYouDead sounds like you're still calling `Element` rather than `Elements`. Note the **s** at the end.

Comment: good catch.  I changed to Elements and now get an error of An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: Sequence contains more than one element

Comment: @ToastedBreadLeavesYouDead In which case there is more than one element called `sr12` returned by your query. You could use `FirstOrDefault` to get the first. It's hard to advise precisely without knowing what your XML looks like or what your specific use case is.

Comment: See my edit - I think I am now providing the XML structure you need to see.

Comment: And my specific use case is - I need to store the value in a variable so that I can Write To Console.