# How can I read merged excel items with c#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office

I have an excel daily program like this:

[image]

I can read excel cells in specific rows or cols. But I want to understand, A,B,C,U,M,S values are Sunday values and C,K,M,S,S,L,L,U values are Monday values. Sunday and Monday is merged cells. Sunday and monday programs have 3 columns but they may have 4 or 5 columns sometimes. So I need to read under values.

Is this possible as programmatically in c#?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the EPPlus library - Create advanced Excel spreadsheets using .NET

https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus

There is a `MergedCells` property on the `ExcelWorksheet` class. You will need to evaluate this property and figure out the column size of Sunday & Monday.

Also, please see the following StackOverflow posts:

- [Get Merged Cell Area with EPPLus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680167/get-merged-cell-area-with-epplus?rq=1)
- [Handle merged cells in Epplus Excel conversion to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416716/handle-merged-cells-in-epplus-excel-conversion-to-html)

Answer (score 0):

Below are the following libraries that could help you parse the merged cells with c#:

EPPlus, Aspose, Microsoft Interop, Spreadsheet gear