# linq - parent/child query to select only lowest level

Tags: linq

Given a common parent/child table:

```
Table A
Column Id int
Column Parent_Id int
Column Description text
```

I would like to only get the nodes that does not have any child nodes.

```
1,null,"PARENT A"
2,null,"PARENT B",
3,null,"PARENT C", 
100,1,"CHILD A1",
101,1,"CHILD A2",
102,2,"CHILD B1"
```

So for my resultset I would like to only get:

Parent C (as it does not have any child elements), and child A1, B2, B1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what exactly you are querying with LINQ, but the general idea is

```
var leafNodes = nodes.Where(n => nodes.Count(n1 => n1.Parent_Id == n.Id) == 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna prefer Any() method instead of Count() == 0. See [Which method performs better: .Any() vs .Count() > 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0)

```
var itemsWithoutChildren = nodes.Where(item=>!nodes.Any(innerItem=>innerItem.Parent_Id==item.Id))
```