# Comparing performance of generated queries for Any() vs Count() in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, performance, t-sql, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I am working with Entity Framework 4.1 and C#.

Which one is the most suitable for best performance?

If so - why? (any links for additional readings) ?

```
bool isBoarding = invoice.Allocations.Where(a => a.Service.Key == "boarding").Count() > 0;
```

**OR**

```
bool isBoarding = invoice.Allocations.Any(a => a.Service.Key == "boarding");
```

Comment: `Any` is more readable and is normally more efficient since it can use `EXISTS`. But in Linq-To-Entities you should look at the generated sql. [Sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11042691/284240) `Count` seems to be faster. For Linq-To-Objects [always](http://stackoverflow.com/a/305156/284240) use `Any`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Count I believe will cause all records to be iterated over, whereas Any will stop at the first it finds.

EDIT: Just found an excellent post about count vs any [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0)

Comment: The post that you link is about Ienumerable but in responses it talk about Iqueriable and EF

Comment: Indeed, In general when using linq to objects Any is almost always faster, however when using Linq to entities Count() > 0 can be faster, purely it seems because of the often convoluted SQL generated by EF.