# want to pass string as true is list have value

Tags: c#

I want to pass value as True if some list has value , for example here

if `item.Achievements.Count()` has value then i need to pass something like this

```
...
item.Location.City + "|" +True + "|" + item.Soid + "|" +
...
```

Code is like this

```
foreach (var item in mgrProfile.GetMemberProfile(context.CurrentMember.MemberProfileSoid).Projects)
{
    bool isdataachivevement = 
    string list = item.Soid+ "|" +
                  item.Soid + "|" +
                  item.ProjectTitle + "|" +
                  item.Role + "|" +
                  item.StartDate.ToShortDateString() + "|" +
                  item.EndDate.value.ToShortDateString() + "|" +
                  item.Location.Country + "|" +
                  item.Location.State + "|" +
                  item.Location.City + "|" +
   // Here is I need to pass as True// if Achievements have data, otherwise false
                  item.Achievements.Count() + "|" +
                  item.Soid + "|" +
                  item.Soid + "|" +
                  item.Soid + "|" +
                  item.Soid + "|" +
                  projectlist.Add(list);
}
```

Comment: what is the problem or error

Comment: not getting the problem

Comment: Can't you just put: `...+(achievementsHaveData?"true":"false")...`

Comment: Late Edit `(.Count > 0).toString();`

Comment: @Sayse Post it as an answer.

Comment: @OscarMederos it feels dirty getting reputation from such an easy answer though :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

`(.Count() > 0).toString();`

Comment: this is correct. Other questions are like: `a == b ? true : false` instead of just `a == b` :)

Comment: i got error at Nullable object must have a value. at (item.Achievements.Count > 0).ToString();

Comment: no sorry my mistake it should be like (.Count() > 0).toString();

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
string list = item.Soid+ "|" +
              item.Soid + "|" +
              item.ProjectTitle + "|" +
              item.Role + "|" +
              item.StartDate.ToShortDateString() + "|" +
              item.EndDate.value.ToShortDateString() + "|" +
              item.Location.Country + "|" +
              item.Location.State + "|" +
              item.Location.City + "|" +
              item.Achievements.Any() + "|" + // <--- Here is a solution
              item.Achievements.Count() + "|" +
              item.Soid + "|" +
              item.Soid + "|" +
              item.Soid + "|" +
              item.Soid + "|" +
              projectlist.Add(list);
```

This will call `ToString()` on the `bool` (`System.Boolean`) which will return either `bool.TrueString` or `bool.FalseString`.

Answer (score 0):

replace line with:

```
(item.Achievements.Count() > 0) ? "true" : "false"
```

or better as suggested in comments if you are using .NET list

```
item.Achievements.Any()
```

Comment: better choice would be to use item.Achievements.Any()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0 ...although to find out how much difference it makes you'd have to profile it.

Answer (score 0):

`Count` is a property:

```
...
item.Location.City + "|" +
item.Achievements.Count > 0 ? "true" : "false" + "|" +
item.Soid + "|" +
...
```

Comment: if `Achievements` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, then it won't be a property.

Comment: @OscarMederos it is a list. Please read the question carefully: "I want to pass value as True **if some list has value** "

Comment: Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

Comment: @SamElliott That's because he's missing a parenthesis in his long expression with `+`.