# Linq query return true or false

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a query where it should return TRUE or FALSE.

```
var query = from c in db.Emp
            from d in db.EmpDetails 
            where c.ID == d.ID && c.FirstName == "A" && c.LastName == "D" 
          // It should return TRUE when this above statement matches all these conditions
```

and I want to attach this query result to a property(of string datatype)

```
this.result = Conert.ToBoolean(query);
```

how to achieve this in LINQ ?

EDIT:

EmpMapper class

```
  public class EmpMapper
  {
    EmpEntities db;
    // ID column already exists in the DB
    private int ID;
    // I am creating this property to add it from the UI side, depending on the certain conditions in the query. That is why I created a separate class to map the existing ID from the DB
    bool result;
    public EmpMapper(int ID, bool result)
    {
      this.db = new EmpEntites();
      this.ID = ID;
      var query = from c in db.Emp
            from d in db.EmpDetails 
            where c.ID == d.ID && c.FirstName == "A" && c.LastName == "D" 
          // It should return TRUE when this above statement matches all these conditions
      this.result = Convert.ToBoolean(query);
    }
   public int ID
   {
    get{return this.ID;}
    set{this.ID = value;}
   }
   public bool result
   {
    get{return this.result;}
    set{this.result = value;}
   }
   }
```

MainViewModel class

```
      List<EmpMapper> empMapCol = new List<EmpMapper>();

     private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      var emp_query = from c in db.Emp
                      orderby c.ID
                      select a;
     List<Emp> empCol = emp_query.ToList();
     foreach(Emp item in empCol)
     {
       this.empMapCol.Add(new EmpMapper(item.ID, item.result)); 
     }
     datagrid1.ItemsSource = empMapCol;
     }
     }
```

Comment: `query` will return one value *per row*. What would you want the result of calling `ToString` to be?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `(query.Count() > 0).ToString()`?

Comment: @jon:i guess he expects a true/false as a string

Comment: @CodeIgnoto: But that makes no sense - what if it's true for one result and false for another?

Comment: I would like to add this result to my DatagridTextcolumn, if the result is True I will display my cell as green & if false display it as red

Comment: @user1221765: How are you intending to add it? Calling `ToString()` on a sequence definitely isn't going to help you.

Comment: @Jon - how can I add this result then ? can I set the result property to bool ?

Comment: Consider to show slightly more code... Side note - "using foreach() to iterate through my class" is very interesting statement - not even sure what it would be.

Comment: Fundamentally, there isn't nearly enough detail/context in this question to answer is sensibly. You've got a lot of information you're not telling us, or telling us in a drip-drip fashion, and the question as it stands doesn't really make sense. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: Sorry that I gave less info, pls see my edited question

Comment: @Alexei I have edited my question, kindly check

Answer (score 38, accepted):

try this,

```
 var query = (from c in db.Emp
        from d in db.EmpDetails 
        where c.ID == d.ID && c.FirstName == "A" && c.LastName == "D"
         select c 
         ).Any(); 

  this.result = query; //no need to convert to boolean its already bool value
```

Comment: The above result worked for me only when I convert it to boolean . Thanks @Saptal Singh

Answer (score 7):

You can use .Any() or .Count(). **Any()** is performing better. (Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0) to see why)

**.Any()**

```
var query = from c in db.Emp
            from d in db.EmpDetails 
            where c.ID == d.ID && c.FirstName == "A" && c.LastName == "D" 
          // It should return TRUE when this above statement matches all these conditions
this.result = query.Any().ToString()
```

**.Count()**

```
var query = from c in db.Emp
            from d in db.EmpDetails 
            where c.ID == d.ID && c.FirstName == "A" && c.LastName == "D" 
          // It should return TRUE when this above statement matches all these conditions
this.result = (query.Count() > 0).ToString()
```

Comment: it's better to not use `Count` as it does unnecessary processing in this particular case

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly you want to get `true` if one of the results of the query matches all conditions. In that case try something like this:

```
var found =
    (from c in db.Emp
    from d in db.EmpDetails
    where c.ID == y.ID && c.FirstName == "A" && c.LastName == "D"
    select c).Any();

this.result = found.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from c in db.Emp
            from d in db.EmpDetails 
            select new { c.ID == y.ID &&  
                         c.FirstName == "A" && 
                         c.LastName == "D" };
```

Comment: There's no reason to use an anonymous type here (I doubt this will even compile) and calling `ToString` on it definitely won't do what's required.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have a "true" or "false" String Response:

```
    public string result
    {
        get
        {
            return db.Emp.SelectMany(c => db.EmpDetails, (c, d) => new {c, d})
                         .Where(@t => c.ID == y.ID && c.FirstName == "A" && c.LastName == "D")
                         .Select(@t => c)).Any().ToString();
        }
    }
```

But I would suggest to make the property "result" a bool and remove the ToString(). 
Once you have a bool you can always do a ToString() on it