# Check if a table is empty with Entity Framework using CodeFirst

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm developing an application using MVVM where i want to use Entity Framwork 5.0. It's my first time using EF, so hope i can explain my problem so you all understand.
My application has a embedded database and im using Code-First approach.

Here is an example to illustrate the problem:
Here i set my Project model which i set as a table in the embedded database, if i understand correct.

```
class CreateDbContext : DbContext
{
    public CreateDbContext() : base() { }

    public CreateDbContext(String nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString) { }

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { set; get; }
}
```

Now in my ProjectViewModel i want to check if the Project table is empty in the database, before doing anything.

```
using (var db = new CreateDbContext())
{
    if(db.Projects <-- checked if this is Tablet is empty ??)
}
```

How should i do that, or is it even possible?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This should work:

```
using (var db = new CreateDbContext())
{
    if(!db.Projects.Any())
    {
        // The table is empty
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey greg84.
That was very simple and works like a charm.
Thanks alot m8

Comment: you should mark it as the answer since it was what you were asking for

Comment: Have already done that, but had to wait 8 minutes before i was able to mark the answer.

Comment: Also don't forget to add `using System.Linq;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Count()`:

```
if(db.Projects.Count() == 0) 
{
    // The table is empty.
}
```

To see the differences between `Any()` and `Count()` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0).

Comment: You can of course do a lot of stupid things, and enumerating ALL records just to ensure the table is empty is one of them. Another one would be deleting all records and comparing whether it made any difference. If not -- the table was empty.