# How to return validation errors from service class methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

Can you give me an example of how to return validation errors from a service class used in a web application. What do you think about this approach below?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using App.Data;
using App.Security;

public interface IMembershipService
{
    bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password, ModelStateDictionary model = null);
}

public class MembershipService : IMembershipService
{
    private DatabaseContext db;

    public MembershipService(DatabaseContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password, ModelStateDictionary model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) || userName.Length > 128 ||
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password) || password.Length > 256)
        {
            TryAddModelError(model, "Username or password provided is incorrect.");
            return false;
        }

        var user = this.db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);

        if (user == null || !PasswordHash.Validate(password, user.PasswordHash, user.PasswordSalt))
        {
            TryAddModelError(model, "Username or password provided is incorrect.");
            return false;
        }

        if (!user.IsApproved)
        {
            TryAddModelError(model, "Your account is suspended.");
            return false;
        }

        user.LastLoginDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        this.db.SaveChanges();

        return true;
    }

    private static void TryAddModelError(ModelStateDictionary model, string errorMessage)
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
            model.AddModelError(string.Empty, errorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage sample:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMembershipService membershipService;

    public AccountController(IMembershipService membershipService)
    {
        this.membershipService = membershipService;
    }

    [HttpPost, AllowAnonymous, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && this.membershipService.ValidateUser(
            model.UserName, model.Password, modelState: ModelState))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is rare to found a C# code with goto

Comment: Fendy, do you know how to rewrite it without goto and still avoid code duplicates?

Comment: Vimel Stan's answer is a clean implementation one without goto.

Comment: Fendy, the problem with Vimel's answer is that validation errors are not exceptions and also there will be duplicate lines of code this way (the ones with error messages)

Comment: Well, you has a strange point of view of DRY. those two may like a duplicated code, but each of it does **different** thing. The principal of DRY is not to repeat/develop same operation twice, not the code if the operation are different.

Comment: Fendy, If two lines are identical, how come they do different things? (the lines with error message "Username or password is incorrect.")

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
public bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) || userName.Length > 128 ||
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password) || password.Length > 256)
    {
        throw new ProviderException("Username and password are required");
    }

    var user = this.db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);

    if (user == null || !PasswordHash.Validate(password, user.PasswordHash, user.PasswordSalt))
    {
        throw new ProviderException("Incorrect password or username");
    }

    return true;
}
```

Usage of Membership service:

```
...
try
{
    var result = membership.ValidateUser(userName, password);
    ...
}
catch (ProviderException e)
{
    model.AddModelError(string.Empty, e.Message);
}
...
```

This way, your `MembershipService` is only responsible for validation and the `ValidateUser` method validates the username and password. What is done with the validation result is up to the user of the `MembershipService`. This is referred to as the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: Its not very good practice to use exceptions to control code flow.

Comment: Vimal, thanks for your suggestion. But validation errors are not exceptional I believe...

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso If you look at the implementation for RoleProviders and MembershipProviders, this is the pattern they follow.

Comment: You could return a string. Empty/Null on success.

Comment: The problem with returning a string is that there could be more than 1 validation error after method is called.

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso Could also return false :) Many ways of solving the same thing, I just provided the code that's similar to a standard implementation.

Comment: Yes, and i think you did well, actually im gonna +1 this answer.
Just launched the exception topic so that the OP can think about that too.

Comment: Setting a Message for an Exception is not the equivalent of returning a string. The message only provides a description of the error state.

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso Please add a link to the topic in the comments, would be easy to track in future.

Comment: Yes but you can return null or empty on success and check the return. Thats one way to do it.

Comment: Also keep in mind, that there might be more than one validation error after a single method call, each of them containing an error message string and field name in the model if any

Comment: @GriefCoder you can return an Enumerable of string errors and empty on success.

Comment: Francisco, instead of true/false ?

Comment: @GriefCoder yes. Your validation method can return an empty collection on success or a collection with string errors on failure.
The caller just need to check the return count()>0

Comment: You'd want to use `Any()` instead of `Count() > 0`, it's more performant. The disadvantage of this approach would be that it's mixing up your validation code along with your other code.

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso Isn't it better to return void, but create a custom exception with collection of error strings? I think it is cleaner this way.

Comment: @VimalStan check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0 -- for collections count()>0 is faster. But that's true for enumerable.
Fendy, that would do it but throwing and catching an exception is quite expensive regarding cpu performance so its not a really good practice to use them to control this kind of situations.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is to throw an exception (usually `InvalidOperationException`).

Long answer, you can create a custom exception to hold the informations you need. Example:

```
public class CustomValidationErrorException : Exception
{
    public string Id { get; set; } // Custom Id for the operation
    public IEnumerable<string> Messages { get; set; } // Multiple validation error message
}
```

Regarding to the requirement, you also can create a custom validation class and ref as a parameter. The parameter usage here is to avoid collision when you want to return an object.

**EDIT:**

There seems some discussion about throwing exception or not during validation. If it is performance matter, I cannot argue, because I'm not expert in that; and during some simple tests that I do, I don't find any performance matter. I will explain in a readability section instead why I prefer `Exceptions` and when it isn't.

**Prefer:**

In API side of view, the code will be easier to read. Consider this service example:

```
public interface ILoginService{
  void Login(string userName, string password);
}
```

Really simple and readable, and from usage point of view

```
public void LoginServiceConsumer(ILoginService service){
  //declare username and password
  service.Login(userName, password);
  // do what after login, if throw exception then this operation will ensure to be cancelled automatically
}
```

No question from my view with the implementation instead. Now, consider returning error messages:

```
public interface ILoginService{
  IEnumerable<string> Login(string userName, string password);
}
```

And from usage point of view

```
public void LoginServiceConsumer(ILoginService service){
  //declare username and password
  IEnumerable<string> validationResult = service.Login(userName, password);
  if(validationResult.Any())
  // do the next operation
}
```

Without **proper documentation or good knowledge to use the object**, now it popped up a question. What is the `IEnumerable<string>` that it returned? Is it **only** return the error message? Will it return "success" as a message when the validation is ok?

Another downside of this technique is, when you returning an object as execution result, but need to validate it first:

```
public MyObject Convert(MySource source){
   if(!source.Valid){
     //give error message here
   }
}
```

How can you do it? One way is to use ref to the message results and assigning it.

```
public MyObject Convert(MySource source, ref List<string> errorMessage){
   if(!source.Valid){
     errorMessage.Add("The source is not valid");
     return null;
   }
}
```

But from usage point of view:

```
public void ConvertConsumer(MySource source){
  List<string> errorMessage = new List<string>(); //you should create a new list
  Convert(MySource source, ref errorMessage); //then pass it
}
```

First, it required a new list. Second, will the user know that it can return null when the validation is bad? Last thing is the same question, What is the `IEnumerable<string>` that it set? Is it **only** set the error message? Will it set "success" as a message when the validation is ok?

**Not Prefer:**

One condition that I not prefer using exception as validation is when your application is tracked for its exceptions using third party, such as AVICode. It can flood your exception report.

Comment: Errors like "Password is invalid", "Your account is disabled", "You exceeded the max number of login attempts" are not exceptional, they are just validation errors, not exceptions..

Comment: `System.FormatException` are also validation error, but .Net treated it as an exception. Just consider the exception as a "general way to show validation error". It will give a standardized usage to the client, especially when you create an API component.

Comment: with exceptions there gonna be also more client code - try/catch, plus forgetting placing try/catch blocks would lead to critical errors at run-time. My pattern (with using model state var) does not have these two problems. So, why don't you like it?

Comment: I've updated my answer to express why I don't prefer it. It is not I don't like it, I just don't prefer it.