# Check if at least one object from a list of objects fulfills condition x

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Is there a better/quicker way to check if from a list of objects at least one object has a certain property?**

```
@{if (Model.StockPositions.Count(x => x.Kaufpreis != 0) > 0) {
```

This will not stop after the first positive hit, will it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well an alternative would be:

```
@{if (Model.StockPositions.Any(x => x.Kaufpreis != 0) {
```

If you're interested in the performance difference between `Count()` and `Any()`, you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0) helpful.

Comment: @peter To answer your second question about stopping.  You are correct in that `Count` must go through every item in the list before it can return a result.  `Any` is more efficient, because it can stop and return a value as soon as the first item that meets the condition is found.