# return list, if empty AND count == 0. jump to else

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have a list of orders...and if the list is empty I want to to jump to the 'else.'

But because its a list (even if its empty) there still is an instance of it? right? anyway if there are no orders it still goes into the if statement so I tried adding `.count == 0`...

but it still goes into the if statement...what do I need to say where if there are no actual records in orders go to 'else....thanks for any replies

```
IEnumerable<OrderRecord> orders = _orderService.GetOrdersByCustomer(id, OrderStatus.Completed).ToArray();

if (orders != null && orders.Count() == 0 )
{
  //order exists
}
else
{
    //no order
}
```

Comment: Don't check for null. It's guaranteed not to be null

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to check if there are more than `0` items in the list

```
if (orders != null && orders.Count() > 0 )
{
    //order exists
}
else
{
    //no order
}
```

The list itself doesn't count as an item.

Or, as suggested by `Richard Ev` in the comments, you can use `orders.Any` which will return true if there are elements in the list.

Comment: Instead of `orders.Count() > 0`, consider using `orders.Any()`. `Any` has the benefit that it does not enumerate the entire collection, which can have a performance impact (if there is a large cost associated with creating an order). It is also arguably more "intentional". Also, it's less to type! :)

Comment: @RichardEv - The flip side would be to simply use the `Count`/`Length` property, as it wouldn't invoke the enumerator at all (if performance was important). Having said that, I think `Any` is not only neater but also has a clear intention for anyone reading.

Comment: good point, I just scrolled right and spotted the `ToArray()` call in the code!

Comment: @RichardEv: Even if it's better to use `Any` for readability, `Enumerable.Count` checks if the input sequence is a collection(like array or list), then it uses the `Count` property, `orders` is an array.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your condition

```
orders.Count() == 0
```

To

```
orders.Count() > 0
```

since currently its check if the list contains no record.

You can also try [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) like:

```
if(orders != null && order.Any())
```

See [why its better to use Any in place of Count()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0)

Comment: Even if it's better to use `Any` for readability, `Enumerable.Count` checks if the input sequence is a collection(like array or list), then it uses the `Count` property, `orders` is an array.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I agree, didn't see the `ToArray` part just concentrated on `So I have a list of orders` :)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to check for `> 0` instead

```
if (orders != null && orders.Count() > 0 )
{
  //order exists
}
```

or `orders.Any()`