# Empty HashSet - Count vs Any

Tags: c#, .net, performance, hashset

I am only interested to know whether a HashSet `hs` is empty or not. 
I am NOT interested to know exactly how many elements it contains.

So I could use this:

```
bool isEmpty = (hs.Count == 0);
```

...or this:

```
bool isEmpty = hs.Any(x=>true);
```

Which one provides better results, performance-wise(specially when the HashSet contains a large number of elements) ?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0

Comment: The C# hashset maintains a count so that's more efficient than finding out if there is a single element. However if you want it to be conditional Any will always be better, because it will stop at the first match.

Comment: You can just use `Any()` rather than supplying a lambda.

Comment: This is micro-optimization questions distract you from your real goal: writing better code :-) Use whatever you think is cleaner. You can also download a .NET decompiler (such as [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)) and check both implementations. `Enumerable.Any` will probably be a tiny bit slower, since it needs to instantiate an enumerator. BTW you probably want something like `bool isEmpty = !hs.Any();`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On a HashSet you can use both, since HashSet internally manages the count.

However, if your data is in an `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` object, using `result.Any()` is preferable over `result.Count()` (Both Linq Methods).

Linq's `.Count()` will iterate through the whole Enumerable, `.Any()` will only peek if any objects exists within the Enumerable or not.

**Update:**
Just small addition: 
In your case with the HashSet `.Count` may be preferable as `.Any()` would require an `IEmumerator` to be created and returned which is a small overhead if you are not going to use the Enumerator anywhere in your code (`foreach`, Linq, etc.). But I think that would be considered "Micro optimization".

Comment: `Linq's .Count() will iterate through the whole Enumerable` It won't with a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 4):

`HastSet<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`, which has a `Count` property, so a call to `Count()` will just call `HastSet<T>.Count`, which I'm assuming is an O(1) operation (meaning it doesn't actually have to *count* - it just returns the current size of the `HashSet`).

`Any` will iterate until it finds an item that matches the condition, then stop.

So in your case, it will just iterate one item, then stop, so **the difference will probably be negligible**.

If you had a *filter* that you wanted to apply (e.g. `x => x.IsValid`) then `Any` would *definitely* be faster since `Count(x => x.IsValid)` would iterate over the entire collection, while `Any` would stop as soon as if finds a match.

For those reasons I generally prefer to use `Any()` rather than `Count()==0` since it's more direct and avoids any potential performance problems.  I would only switch to `Count()==0` if it provided a *significant* performance boost over `Any()`.

Note that `Any(x=>true)` is logically the same as calling `Any()`.  That doesn't change your question, but it looks cleaner without the lambda.

Comment: No. `.Any()` parameterless won't iterate until it stops. `.Any(x => x)` will because it has to evaluate the contents. All the parameterless has to do is reset the enumerator and call  `enumerator.GetNext()` and return it's result to find out if there are any results. `.Any(x => x)` will have to check the actually contents

Comment: @Tseng `.Any(x=>true)` will evaluate the first item, find that it resolves to true, and then evaluate no more.  It's a negligible amount more work than just `.Any()`.  The primary advantage of using the parameterless overload is just that it's faster to type and (arguably) a bit clearer to the reader.

Comment: You're right. I've overseen the fact that the it returns a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of collection, it may or may not matter performance-wise. So why not just use `hs.Any()` since that is designed for exactly what you need to know?

And the lambda expression `x => true` has no meaning here. You can leave that out.