# How to know if IEnumerable<XElement> is empty

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

How to I know if the Item is null(empty)?

```
xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> item =
from el in xmlDoc.Descendants("Item")
      where (string)el.Attribute("Name") == "Google"
      select el;
```

something instead of `if(item==null )`

Comment: Perhaps `item.Any()` is what you want. Items might be a better name.

Comment: Why not `item==null` not sure how else will you know if it is null or not

Comment: @V4Vendetta because it is not null. it is an empty object, but not null.

Comment: @user990635 Ok so probably you could compare it with Enumerable [Empty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [**`item.Any()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) to check for item exist

You can check `Count` as well but I prefer to have `Any` with `IEnumerable<T>`

check this out [Which method performs better: .Any() vs .Count() > 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0)