# Is there a better way to search a list with another list

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a better linq query to see if a list contains any item in another list than the following:

```
results.Where(r => r.Categories.Intersect(submittedCategories).Count() > 0)
```

where `r.categories` is the list of categories the result is in and `submittedCategories` i a list of categories the user want to filter on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of [`Enumerable.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
results.Where(r => r.Categories.Intersect(submittedCategories).Any())
```

Method `Count()` has optimization for sources which implement `ICollection` (it simply returns `Count` property value of collection). But result of [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will be `IEnumerable<T>` so in this case `Count()` will iterate over all set:

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)    
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");

    ICollection<TSource> is2 = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (is2 != null)    
        return is2.Count;

    ICollection is3 = source as ICollection;
    if (is3 != null)    
        return is3.Count;

    int num = 0;
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext()) // you will fall into this case
           num++; 
    }
    return num;
}
```

It means that full intersection should be built from both collections to know total count of items in result. And only then value will be compared with zero.

`Any()` will stop iterating just after first item will be found without finding all items which intersect.

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)    
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");

    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())        
            return true;        
    }
    return false;
}
```

Another benefit - `Any()` shows your intent better.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a better linq query to see if a list contains **any** item in
>   another list

If you are looking for any item matching then use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `Count()`

```
results.Where(r => r.Categories.Intersect(submittedCategories).Any())
```

You may see where `Any` would be better for `Count()`: [Which method performs better: .Any() vs .Count() > 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `Any` directly without `Intersect`:

```
results.Where(r => r.Categories.Any(submittedCategories.Contains))
```

Comment: It worth noting that you are not simply removing usage of `Intersect` - you are *replacing* it with usage of `Contains`. And here comes important thing: Any+Contains has complexity O(N*M). Intersect+Any requires additional memory, but has complexity O(N+M)

Answer (score 1):

Try using Any() method.

Any receives a Predicate. It determines if any element in a collection matches a certain condition.

Source: [Dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/any)