# Which is better when check a list is null : not null or use Any

Tags: c#

Which is better when check list is null ?

```
var newList;

if(newList!= null)

or newList.Any()
```

In the above code, sometimes I check not null and sometimes I use Any(), I don't know which one is best practice and why ?

Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Best practice is not to leave a bug in your code. `Any()` will throw Null exception if `newList` is actually `null`

Comment: You can't use `newList.Any()` if `nesList` is `null`.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Checking for empty or null List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390005/checking-for-empty-or-null-liststring).

Comment: I don't understand why this kind of questions get upvotes and even answers with upvotes these days.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are not the same.

`Any` will throw an exception if used on a `null` reference.

With lists, you can think of `.Any()` as `.Count() != 0` (*)

You may have to check for both, and you have to do the null check before calling `Any()` on your `IEnumerable`.

One way is to check them for both in one strike with the null-safe navigation `?.`as in  [Thierry V's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52661230/479251).

But sometimes you want to throw a custom Exception if you have a null value that you are not supposed to have, and treat an empty list as a correct input, so it all depends on the context.

Just remember that these are different.

(*) : as noticed in a comment, `.Any()` is not actually implemented as `Count() == 0`. For lists, it's functionally equivalent, but it's best practice to use `Any()` to test if an `IEnumerable` is empty or not, because `Count()` might need to go through all the elements.

Comment: In general, for sequences that are not `List`s, `Count() != 0` differs from `Any()` as it scrolls the entire sequence to calculate the number of items (that could be infinite!) before comparing it with 0. `Any()`, instead, returns as soon as an item is found or when the sequence is empty.

Comment: @LucaCremonesi indeed. Thanks for the comment. For the sake of correctness, I tried to formulate this point in the answer. Feel free to edit if you want and see a better phrasing.

Answer (score 5):

`null` and `Any()` have the different purpose.

`Any` is used to check your list if it contains any item.

Before calling `Any`, your list must be not `null`, it not, it throws Null exception.

Think about `newList?.Any()`

Answer (score 3):

As other answers say `!= null` and `Any()`  are different

I would write an extension method to make you expect.

```
public static class ExtenstionArray
{
    public static bool CheckAny<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list) {
        return list != null && list.Any();
    }
}
```

then you can use easier to check.

```
if(newList.CheckAny())
```