# Boolean version to see if list has any values

Tags: c#

Wondering if there is a way to check how to return if a `List<>` has any values in it. Usually I will try something like `if(List.Count>0)` but is there another way, that returns Boolean preferably?

Comment: What's wrong with `(List.Count > 0)`? I hope this isn't about thinking a bool comparison is faster...

Comment: On performance between .Count and .Any(): http://stackoverflow.com/a/305156/1141432

Comment: Summarizing: for clarity, `Any()`. For speed, `.Count`.

Comment: @Andrew not quite, `.Any` for speed when you have `IEnumerable` since `.Count` must enumerate and count.

Comment: Clarity? Only in the eyes of some beholders..

Comment: @crashmstr When you say IEnumerable, you mean List as well right?

Comment: @RealWorldCoder a `List<T>` can get `Count` in O(1), in other words it *knows* the count of objects. If you then do a `Where` getting an `IEnumerable<T>`, `Count` will have to enumerate and count the items in the collection, so O(n).

Comment: There is a difference between `.Count` and `.Count()`.. `IEnumerable<T>` does not have a `.Count` property. But if people want to know the details, just read Marc Gravell's answer. It is way better than any comment here.

Comment: @TaW, of course it's a very slight difference in clarity. I liked T.J.Kjaer's comment to that Marc Gravell's answer: *"It signals the precise intent of the developer. If you are not interested in knowing the number of items, but only if there are some, then somecollection.Any() is simpler and clearer than somecollection.Count > 0"*.

Comment: @crashmstr, I based my comment on Marc Gravell's answer, which states that *"if you are starting with something that has a .Length or .Count (such as ICollection<T>, IList<T>, List<T>, etc) - then this will be the fastest option"*. And in this case, it's a `List<>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is using Linq:

```
if(myList.Any())
{ /* do something */ }
```