# Does LINQ make use of underlying data structure?

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

Take a look for example at the accepted answer here [Which method performs better: .Any() vs .Count() > 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/305156/210342). Now I wonder if LINQ functions (e.g. `Last`, `FirstOrDefault`) are completely naive and all they do is enumerating/checking `IEnumerable` or they check what data structure is beneath (at least for basic collections like `Array`, `List`) and the execution is optimized for such structures?

Comment: To save you *wondering*, http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Utils/CollectionExtensions.cs,172d0a44454c0d97

Comment: If you have read the accepted answer there you know it does so at least some of the time. And sometimes not.

Comment: @christiandev, thank you, weird those extensions are marked as `internal` though.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, of course I am not interested in particular case, but general rule. But it seems, the rule is "there is no rule" :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do where it makes sense, typically not for the actual type but for an interface (for example they check for IList when it helps speedup)