# Remove items not in list not working properly

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have two list of `T`, I need to remove from list `A` all the elements that are not in list `B`. I did this:

```
A.RemoveAll(item => !B.Contains(item));
```

this working pretty well, but if the list `B` does not contains any elements, this code will remove all the items from the list `A` and it shouldn't. Why happen that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it removes everyhing because the condition is true for all items in list A.

Since you want to remove only items from A if list B is **not** empty:

```
if(B.Any())
    A.RemoveAll(item => !B.Contains(item));
```

Comment: Using the `Any()` method on `List<T>`/`ICollection<T>` isn't good idea because it uses enumerators instead of the `Count` property.

Comment: @YohDeadfall: so what? But `Any` is more menaingful than counting items. Especially with collections the overhead of `Any` is negligible. With other types you have to use it anyway. However, checking it once is always better than [checking it for every item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49385931/284240). In other words: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0#comment4595700_305156

Answer (score 0):

This happens because list B doesn't contain any items. And you are saying remove everything from A that doesn't exist in B. Effectively saying remove everything because B doesn't have anything

Answer (score 0):

Well it happens because if `B` is empty, for **all** elements in `A` the expression `!B.Contains(item)` is `true`.

Try this:

```
A.RemoveAll(item => B.Count > 0 && !B.Contains(item));
```

or better avoid iterating at all if `B` is empty:

```
if (B.Count > 0) A.RemoveAll(item => !B.Contains(item));
```

Comment: This works perfectly thanks! I don't understand why you should edit the question with Any instead of Count, maybe the other user can explain it

Answer (score -1):

It happens because `!B.Contains(item)` returns true for all elements from `A`. If you don't want this to happen, just check if `B` is not empty:

```
A.RemoveAll(item => B.Any() && !B.Contains(item));
```