# IEnumerable<>.Count vs IEnumerable.ToList().Count

Tags: c#, collections

I am trying to find if a list is Empty. Whats the most efficient way.

```
IEnumerable<int> TestProp={get; set;}
```

this TestProb will be populated by another method. when I try to check if list is empty and I have to do this many times few 100s atleast.
Right now I see it as

```
var cnt=TestProp.ToList().Count>0;
```

I know `IEnumerable` will try to find Count property by converting to ICollection but what I am looking here is best performant way for finding non empty list. I somehow feel `ToList()` is not needed here.

Comment: In many cases `TestProp.Any()` will be the fastest way to check for empty collection. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/305156/2011071

Answer (score 2):

you can write your own extension

```
public static bool NotNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source != null && source.Any();
}
```

and call

```
if (TestProp.NotNullOrEmpty())
```

or you can use

```
if (TestProp?.Any() == true)
```

but you must be compare with boolean value so you cannot use like this

```
if (TestProp?.Any())
```

because `TestProp?.Any()` will return `Nullable<bool>`

Answer (score 2):

In general, the answer is to use `.Any()`
If you want a more complete answer you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0)