# Difference between linq to entities and linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Entity Framework vs LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql)

What is the difference between linq to entities & linq to sql?

Why linq to entities came into picture?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 1):

linq to sql is being discontinued.

linq to entities is MS's new thing and will be replacing their linq to sql stuff.

Comment: Hmm. Linq to Entities has nothing to do with Linq to SQL, except it uses the same Linq syntax. They're for completely different data access mechanisms.

It may be more accurate to say that Microsoft is investing more in Entity Framework than Linq to SQL, but even that's not completely clear.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to SQL is for direct queries using SQL Server, regardless of using Entity Framework.

Linq to Entities is Linq used while using Microsoft's Entity Framework, regardless of db server.

Comment: LINQ to SQL also has support for practically any other database with dblinq (an open source, drop in assembly replacement) see http://dblinq.codeplex.com/.