# DB Agnostic ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, postgresql, portability

we are making an ASP.Net application. We would like to have our application to be at least sorta DB agnostic, most notable to be compatible with both SQL Server and PostgreSQL. What is the best way of doing this? What are some of the common pitfalls? Also is there a class or something that already abstracts away the difference between things like `SqlConnection` and whatever PostgreSQL uses for connections?

(We are wanting to be DB agnostic so we can use PostgreSQL here(in development and later in our own hosting) due to price and let our self-hosting clients use Sql Server if they so wish)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All ADO.Net providers extend the basic interfaces:

- [IDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection.aspx)
- [IDbTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbtransaction.aspx)
- [IDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.aspx)
- [IDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx)
- [IDbDataParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbdataparameter.aspx)

So in theory you can write your whole DAL (Data Access Layer) against the abstract interfaces and leverage any provider, including 3rd party ones like MySQLs. In practice, no mortal ever managed to pull this trick. The interfaces are very hard to program against on one hand, and any application beyond a demo-ware will quickly run into the wall of SQL dialects incompatibility.

A more feasable approach is to settle for a number of target destinations and develope specific DALs. Entity Framework and repository pattern and nHibernate and all such help, but none solves the fundamental issues.

Comment: +1 for "no mortal ever managed to pull this trick". LOL.  Sadly, you are quite right.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Entity Framework. That way you would have a single programming model to work against.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx

http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/

Comment: The Entity framework will not work for us. Some of our tables are dynamically created/altered and almost every query done on the database must be built by our application at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use ADO.NET directly, you can use the DbProviderFactory to abstract away the provider (SqlClient, OleDb etc) that you are using.  Usually you use this in conjunction with the <connectionStrings> configuration element, with code something like:

```
ConnectionStringSettings c = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name];
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(c.ProviderName)
...
IDbConnection connection = _factory.CreateConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = c.ConnectionString;
...
```

There's lots of info in MSDN.

Of course this doesn't help you with differences in SQL syntax between different providers - you need a lowest common denominator approach to work with multiple providers.  This affects things like the syntax for parameters (e.g. @ prefix for SQL Server, positional parameters only for OleDb, ...).

Comment: I think the most difficult thing is the quotes because MySQL for example uses backticks for quotes while others use single quotes adn yet others use double quotes... Other than that, I can handle using only ANSI Sql syntax and where neededed using a `if(postgresql_in_use){...`

Answer (score 0):

I just create an interface for my data source and then implement it for each data source type I need to use. Normally they look something like this:

```
public interface IMyProjectDataSource
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetUserNames();
    void AddUser(string userName);
}

public class SqlServerMyProjectDataSource : IMyProjectDataSource
{
    public SqlServerMyProjectDataSource(string connectionString)
    {
        //...
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetUserNames()
    {
        //...
    }

    public void AddUser(string userName)
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class PostgreSqlMyProjectDataSource : IMyProjectDataSource
{

    public IEnumerable<string> GetUserNames()
    {
        //...
    }

    public void AddUser(string userName)
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class HttpCacheSqlMyProjectDataSource : IMyProjectDataSource
{
    public HttpCacheSqlMyProjectDataSource(IMyProjectDataSource parentMyProjectDataSource)
    {

    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetUserNames()
    {
        //...
    }

    public void AddUser(string userName)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

I also like this because it allows you to "chain" them together. For instance you can do all of your data source caching like this:

```
public class HttpCacheSqlMyProjectDataSource : IMyProjectDataSource
{
    public HttpCacheSqlMyProjectDataSource(IMyProjectDataSource parentMyProjectDataSource)
    {
            //...
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetUserNames()
    {
        //...
    }

    public void AddUser(string userName)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The hardest part is deciding how to create it, especially if you're planning to chain more than one together. For that I generally store it in my Global.asax.cs as a singleton and create it from a type name in the .config file. You can use Type.GetType() and then Activator.CreateInstance() to do that and most of the chaining I have will be done no matter what the data source in the .config is so I don't have to worry about creating some sort of "constructor" type or a complicated .config.

Hopefully that makes sense. This may not be the best for all situations but I have had a lot of luck with it.

Comment: This is a DAL (Data Access Layer).  It's a good design concept, but still leaves you with the burden of implementing each storage type.  ORM solutions take this burden from you (though they also have downsides).

Comment: I am away this is a DAL. I'm not a very big fan of most ORM solutions because of requirements they put on how they are going to get the data, can I use stored procedures? Can I do more than one database call if I need to? Etc. Also I'm not always in control of my database to the extent I would need to use them because of my companies DBA's so I normally just end up using this.

Comment: @dukk: Good ORMs don't generally limit your ability to drop down to ADO.NET (or whatever you need) to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is an option as mentioned by Shiraz.  You might also consider other ORM solutions such as [NHibernate](http://www.hibernate.org).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for database-agnostic applications is usually an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) ([this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orm)). There are [plenty of them](http://www.shrinkrays.net/articles/a-look-at-net-object-relational-mapper-orms.aspx) for .NET - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132676/which-orm-for-net-would-you-recommend) will give you some guidance on which one to choose.

The three most popular ones are:

- [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/)
- <del>[Linq-to-SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) (now superceded by [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx)) - used by Stackoverflow.com.</del> SQL Server only
- [Subsonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/)

Comment: EF doesn't really supercede Linq2Sql.  They share a lot of similarity, but also substantial differences.  Most important to this question is Linq2Sql ONLY supports Sql Server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql/259058#259058 , for #2 linq-to-sql supports anything with an OLEDB driver, or older ODBC.

Comment: From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386929.aspx
Provider Model 
Q. Is a public provider model available? 
A. No public provider model is available. At this time, LINQ to SQL supports SQL Server and SQL Server Compact 3.5 only.

Comment: I stand corrected. I admit I was going on the server explorer which gives you Oracle and odbc/oledb.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to go with some sort of Repository Pattern.

It's not a silver bullet that will save you from hacking for each DBMS flavour, but that is the way to go if you want it to be maintainable from the beginning, something that ORMs just do not provide.

http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/04/07/asp-net-mvc-mvc-storefront-part-2

Answer (score 0):

At a very high level you would want to use something that abstracts your database more than just the SqlConnection, SqlCommand, and Sql* classes. So when people say to use ORMs, they're pretty much right. The ORMs provide that level of abstraction for you.

But for abstracting away SqlCommand and SqlConnection there are interfaces in the System.Data namespace. IDbConnection, IDbCommand, etc. are already inside the framework and you can code against those. The issue then is finding kind of way to create the concrete classes and you can tackle that using an IoC container or a provider pattern.