# what is the difference between linq to sql class and entity framework

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Entity Framework vs LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql)

what is the difference between linq to sql class and entity framework and what kind of situation linq to sql should use and when entity framework will be the best option.

Comment: The question is already answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549638/difference-between-linq-to-sql-and-entity-framework, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [this link](http://www.dotcominfoway.com/blog/linq-to-sql-vs-ado-net-entity-framework) for a quick comparison.
For me linq to sql is a quicker way to get a small application up and running and the entity framework is more for large more complex applications that you can take time to build a big foundation for.