# LINQ multi-table query - only 2 of 3 tables are returned

Tags: asp.net, linq, multi-table

**QUERY:**  I want to return all restaurants with a CUISINE__BANE = cusisineName regardless of the city in which they are located.  My query returns the RESTAURANT and CITY tables but not the CUISINE table.  Your help is greatly appreciated!

```
public class DLgetRestaurants
    {
        DL.FVRGDataContext db = new FVRGDataContext();

        public List<RESTAURANT> getRestaurants(string cuisineName)
        {
            var cuisineID = db.CUISINEs.First(s => s.CUISINE_NAME == cuisineName).CUISINE_ID;

            List<RESTAURANT> result = (from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs
                                       join CITY in db.CITies on RESTAURANT.CITY_ID equals CITY.CITY_ID
                                       join CUISINE in db.CUISINEs on RESTAURANT.CUISINE_ID equals CUISINE.CUISINE_ID
                                       where RESTAURANT.CUISINE_ID == cuisineID
                                       select RESTAURANT).ToList();

             return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Accept some of your other question's answers before asking new questions

Comment: sorry, I thought I had accepted everything.  I will check again.

Comment: You need to click on the Check Mark beside the question that helps you solve your problem

Comment: Don't quite understand the question, you currently return a list of restaurants, can you explain *"My query returns the RESTAURANT and CITY tables but not the CUISINE table."*

Comment: This is a restaurant review site.  The user selects a cuisine and all the restaurants having that cuisine are selected.  The query should return the cusine name, the restaurant name and the city name.  I have used the O/R designer to create the entity classes for all the tables in my design.  Does that help???  ~susan~

Comment: Thanks Aducci.  I have been leaving all these comments saying thanks and thought that was enuf.  My aplogies for any lack of courtesy (my bad!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that your query *actually* does return the City - you currently only select the restaurant in your query, instead you could project to a special type that has the info you want:

```
class RestaurantByCuisine
{
  public string RestaurantName {get;set;}
  public string CityName {get;set;}
  public string CuisineName {get;set;}
}

public List<RestaurantByCuisine> getRestaurants(string cuisineName)
{
    var cuisineID = db.CUISINEs.First(s => s.CUISINE_NAME == cuisineName).CUISINE_ID;

    List<RestaurantByCuisine> result = (from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs
                                join CITY in db.CITies on RESTAURANT.CITY_ID equals CITY.CITY_ID
                                join CUISINE in db.CUISINEs on RESTAURANT.CUISINE_ID equals CUISINE.CUISINE_ID
                                where RESTAURANT.CUISINE_ID == cuisineID
                                select new RestaurantByCuisine() 
                                { 
                                    RestaurantName = RESTAURANT.Name,
                                    CityName = CITY.Name,
                                    CuisineName = CUISINE.Name
                              ).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

This assumes you entities have a `Name` property, substitute with the right property name otherwise.

Note that your Restaurant entity already has `CITY_ID`, `CUISINE_ID` properties, so *if* this is a foreign key to the respective tables you also should have `CITY` and `CUISINE` properties. These will be populated if you use an `Include()` query on these properties, the query would then look like this:

```
List<RESTAURANT> result = (from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs.Include(x => x.CITY).Include(x => x.CUISINE)
                            where RESTAURANT.CUISINE_ID == cuisineID
                            select RESTAURANT
                            ).ToList();
```

**Edit:**

It sounds like you are using Linq to Sql, in this case you can specify the load options directly on your data context:

```
DL.FVRGDataContext db = new FVRGDataContext();
var dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<RESTAURANT>(r => r.CITY);
dlo.LoadWith<RESTAURANT>(r => r.CUISINE);
db.LoadOptions = dlo;
```

Then the following should work:

```
List<RESTAURANT> result = (from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs
                           where RESTAURANT.CUISINE_ID == cuisineID
                           select RESTAURANT
                           ).ToList();
```

Comment: I am receiving the following error on 'RestaurantByCuisine':  The type or namespace could not be found.

Comment: @Susan: It sounds like you are using Linq to Sql, try out my last suggestion.

Comment: Do I need a using statement or assembly reference to use DataLoadOptions ... I'm getting the red line from Intellisense.

Comment: Added:  using System.Data.Linq;  Now I'm getting an error on the db.LoadOptions statement:  Setting load options is not allowed after results have been returned from a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can also re-do your select like this:

```
        List<RESTAURANT> result = (from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs.Include("CITY").Include("CUISINE")
                                   where RESTAURANT.CUISINE_ID == cuisineID
                                   select RESTAURANT).ToList();
```

Comment: Oh boy!  I tried for a week to figure out the INCLUDE but Intellisense did not recognize the syntax.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with the creation of the entity framework classes???  I created the entity classes by dragging the tables to the O/R designer.  I can see the table relationships in the view.  Any suggestions???

Comment: Is what I gave you working?  I'm not sure what you mean about not getting the Include on intelisense.  Intelisense won't tell you what tables you can include, that's up to you.

Comment: Error 2 'System.Data.Linq.Table<DL.RESTAURANT>' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Linq.Table<DL.RESTAURANT>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) H:\ASP.Net\FVRG\DL\DLgetRestaurants.cs 28 74 DL

Comment: These are the steps I took:  (1) created my tables with relationships, (2) created LINQ to SQL dbml, (3) dragged my tables into the Object Relationsal Designer.  I thought that I am using entity classes and hence entity framework ... is that correct. ~susan~

Comment: No, Entity Framework uses an ADO Entity Data Model (Edmx).  Here is a good link with an answer on the differences.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 0):

What is it you are trying to achieve here? If you simply need to access the `Cuisine` from each `Restuarant` you will be able to iterate through the `List<Restuarant>` like so...

```
List<Restuarant> restuarants = GetList(); // Get the list however you like.
foreach(var r in restuarants)
{
     // Now you can access Cuisine
     var cuisine = r.Cuisine;
}
```

You can also get a list of `Cuisine` like this...

```
var cuisines = restuarants.Where(c => c.CuisineName == "chips").ToList();
```

Or something similar.