# How to select multiple Variables using Lambda expression c#

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a object of class 'PersonnelVehicle' which has structure as below:

```
public class PersonnelVehicle
{
    private Guid _personnelId;
    public Guid PersonnelId
    {
        get
        {
            return _personnelId;
        }
    }

    private int _Age;
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return _Age;
        }
    }
    private string _personnelName;
    public string PersonnelName
    {
        get
        {
            return _personnelName;
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to fetch single element using lambda expression

i.e ObjectPersonnel.Select(x=>x.PersonnelId)

1) But how to fetch multiple elements

i.e Age and PersonnelName from this object using Lambda expression?

2) Also, if I have structure for PersonnelVehicle as below,

```
public class PersonnelVehicle
{
public ObservableCollection<PersonnelModel> Personnel_List = new    ObservableCollection<PersonnelModel>
        {
             new PersonnelModel{ID=Guid.NewGuid(),Name="Mr.Joe",Gender="Male",Hospital="Poly Clinic",EMPID="abc 123",Capabilities="123",Position="Assistant",Title="Test",Status="General",ICNumber="IC 123",Roles="Test"},
             new PersonnelModel{ID=Guid.NewGuid(),Name="Su Su",Gender="Female",Hospital="Clementi Clinic",EMPID="abc 1234",Capabilities="1234",Position="Security",Title="Test",Status="General",ICNumber="IC 1234",Roles="Test"},
              new PersonnelModel{ID=Guid.NewGuid(),Name="Ms Tan",Gender="Female",Hospital="Bishan Clinic",EMPID="abc 1235",Capabilities="1235",Position="HR",Title="Test",Status="General",ICNumber="IC 1235",Roles="Test"},
        };
}
```

How to fetch all the list of IDs and Positions using same way?

Note: I need only in Lambda expressions, so its different question from this link: [Linq Syntax - Selecting multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772267/linq-syntax-selecting-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 3):

Use an [*anonymous type*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)

```
ObjectPersonnel.Select(x=> new { x.PersonnelId , x.Age }),
```

Comment: If I have object Personnel_List inside 'ObjectPersonnel' as below,

Personnel_List = new ObservableCollection<PersonnelModel>
            {
                 new PersonnelModel{ID=Guid.NewGuid(),Name="Mr.Joe",Gender="Male",EMPID="abc 123",Capabilities="123",Position="Assistant",Title="Test",Status="General",ICNumber="IC 123",Roles="Test"},new PersonnelModel{ID=Guid.NewGuid(),Name="Su Su",Gender="Female",EMPID="abc 1234",Capabilities="1234",Position="Security",Title="Test",Status="General",ICNumber="IC 1234",Roles="Test"},};

how to fetch just ID and Gender?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to name the variables in there?

```
ObjectPersonnel.Select(x=> new { PersonnelId = x.PersonnelId , Age = x.Age })
```